# How to remove row by range condition in a column using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have several data frames which has the following format:

| sequence | range | sequence_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| K142442 | 283-423 | 58654 |
| K142442 | 283-414 | 58322 |
| K142442 | 192-342 | 36762 |
| K123123 | 771-250 | 21456 |
| K123123 | 771-250 | 76846 |
| K123123 | 771-250 | 41234 |
| K343232 | 320-642 | 82657 |
| K343232 | 320-642 | 36245 |
| K343232 | 1670-1521 | 25264 |

(showing the relevant columns for time issues)

As you notice, there are some ranges (range column) that are repeated along the same sequences (sequence column) as shown in the table. So I'm trying to remove those redundant rows by looking the same **range starting number from left to right**.

In brief, if for example the sequence K142442 has 3 representatives as shown in the table, but two of these representatives have the same initial range (283 in the table) I only want to keep the sequence with the longer range of those sequences in the table.

This is the example data frame:

```
df = data_frame(sequence = c(rep("K142442",3),rep("K123123",3),
             rep("343232",3)),
range = c("283-423","283-414","192-342","771-250","771-250",
          "771-250","320-642","320-642","1670-1521"),
sequence_ID = c(58645,58322,36762,21456,76846,41232,82657,36246,25264))
```

Desired output:

| sequence | range | sequence_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| K142442 | 283-423 | 58654 |
| K142442 | 192-342 | 36762 |
| K123123 | 771-250 | 21456 |
| K343232 | 320-642 | 82657 |
| K343232 | 1670-1521 | 25264 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could extract the minimum value from the 'range' column, use that as grouping column to get the `first` value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(sequence, min_range = readr::parse_number(range)) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(range, sequence_ID), first), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  select(-min_range)%>% 
  arrange(match(sequence, df$sequence), match(range, df$range))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  sequence range     sequence_ID
  <chr>    <chr>           <dbl>
1 K142442  283-423         58645
2 K142442  192-342         36762
3 K123123  771-250         21456
4 343232   320-642         82657
5 343232   1670-1521       25264
```

---

Or with `distinct`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
 separate(range, into = c('min_range', 'max_range'), remove = FALSE) %>% 
 distinct(sequence, min_range, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
 select(-min_range, -max_range)
```

If the ranges are not ordered, then we can also do

```
df %>% 
  separate(range, into = c('min_range', 'max_range'), 
      remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(sequence, min_range) %>%
  slice_max(n =1, order_by = max_range, with_ties = FALSE) %>% 
  ungroup%>% 
  select(names(df)) %>% 
  arrange(match(sequence, df$sequence), match(range, df$range))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  sequence range     sequence_ID
  <chr>    <chr>           <dbl>
1 K142442  283-423         58645
2 K142442  192-342         36762
3 K123123  771-250         21456
4 343232   320-642         82657
5 343232   1670-1521       25264
```

Comment: Thanks so much! it worked!. There is a little question here and it is if the data frames are under a for loop, how do I call the columns for the dataframes? In particular on the match(sequence, df$sequence) part, how do I call the sequence column without using df$sequence?

Comment: @Valentin if you have a list of data.frames `lst1 <- list(df1, df2)` inside the for loop, you may have to extract the data.frame with `[[`, i.e. `for(i in seq_along(lst1)) lst1[[i]] %>...` and the `match(sequence, lst1[[i]]$sequence)` if I understand the issue

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using `str_extract`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(range = factor(range, levels = unique(range))) %>% 
  group_by(group = str_extract(range, '^\\d+')) %>% 
  slice_max(str_extract(range, '\\d+$'), with_ties=FALSE) %>% 
  arrange(range) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group)
```

```
  sequence range     sequence_ID
  <chr>    <fct>           <int>
1 K142442  283-423         58654
2 K142442  192-342         36762
3 K123123  771-250         21456
4 K343232  320-642         82657
5 K343232  1670-1521       25264
```

Answer (score 0):

To add onto @akrun's answer, one could also do:

```r
df |> 
  tidyr::separate(col = "range", into = c("start", "end")) |> 
  dplyr::group_by(sequence, start) |> 
  dplyr::summarise(
    end = max(end), 
    sequence_ID = sequence_ID[which.max(end)], 
    .groups = "drop"
  ) |> 
  tidyr::unite(col = "range", start:end, sep = "-", remove = TRUE)
```

```r
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   sequence range     sequence_ID
#>   <chr>    <chr>           <dbl>
#> 1 K123123  771-250         21456
#> 2 K142442  192-342         36762
#> 3 K142442  283-423         58645
#> 4 K343232  1670-1521       25264
#> 5 K343232  320-642         82657
```

Answer (score 0):

In base `R` :

```
df[c("min" , "max")] <- do.call(rbind , strsplit(df$range , "-"))
df$min <- as.integer(df$min)
ag <- aggregate(max ~ sequence + min , df , max)

sequence_ID <- list()
j <- 1
for (i in ag$max){
  sequence_ID[[j]] <- df$sequence_ID[which(i == df$max)[1]]
  j <- j + 1
}

cbind(ag , sequence_ID = unlist(sequence_ID))
```